# How to do camel filter using Xpath or condition

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

```
<SterlingMessage Action="CREATE" DocumentType="0005"
     MessageType="employee" 
    <empClass Createts="2017-02-21T23:30:35-06:00"
        EmpType="Contract" .../>
...
/>
```

IN camel, I need to filter **EmpType= "contract" OR "fulltime"** .Anyone help on this ?

Comment: Whats wrong with "//empClass[@EmpType='Contract' or @EmpType='Fulltime']" ?

Comment: getting  Definition has no children on Filter error

Comment: we have kafka topic , read only fulltime or contract and need to ignore other message in the camel